# Error while installing dbeaver - Java error code = 13

Tags: java, dbeaver

I am getting the below error when trying to open dbeaver.  Java is up to date...any ideas?

[image: Below is a copy of the error]

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you resolve this?

Comment: Found an quick solution, you just need to download the latest version of java runtime envioroment (JRE) and that will do the trick http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem this morning. There are two practical ways to solve it:

- Download the right version (probably DBeaver 64Bit version). You must actually find out which JRE-version your computer is running.
- Change the JVM DBeaver is using: Go to the DBeaver-directory and add the lines below on the top of the `dbeaver.ini` file. Be aware that the **line break is important!**

  ```
  -vm  
  C:/path/to/your/jdk/jdk-8u144-windows-x64/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll
  ```

  Of course you must have the right jdk installed where the directory is pointing to.

Comment: In Ubuntu, I just added "-vm /my/java8-dir/bin/java" into dbeaver.ini.

Comment: For me, it was enough to add `-vm \n
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\bin` (Windows obviously). The linebreak was important. Without it, DBeaver didn't start.

Comment: I've used like `-vm
D:\Progs\Java64\bin` PS: 'D:\Progs\Java64\bin' part must be in the new line.

Answer (score 10):

I downloaded the 64bit zip version of Dbeaver and I got the same error.
So I downloaded the 32bit zip version and that worked fine.
I assume I have a 32bit version of java VM installed.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with DBveaver version 6.0.1 only the 64-bit version is available and I had to install 64-bit JRE to make it work.

https://dbeaver.io/download/

> 32-bit versions were obsolete in version 6.0.1 and later (because both
>   Java and Eclipse platform are no longer support 32 bit). If you need
>   32-bit version of DBeaver then you can download version 6.0.0 or
>   earlier or use DBeaver Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

It was a long time ago, but maybe it will help one or the other.

In my case I installed DBeaver for myself as a user and my username contained the character #. So I got this error message.

I reinstalled DBeaver for 'all users' and it worked.